# How to initialize a pointer outside of main?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, initialization

I am trying to implement nodelist in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int value;
    void *next;
} node_t;

void printlist(node_t*head){
    for(node_t*i=head;i;i=i->next)
        printf("%i\n",i->value);
}

node_t create(int value){
    node_t *ret = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    ret->value=value;
    ret->next=0;
    return *ret;
}

int main(){
    int i=0;
    node_t*head=0;
    for(node_t*tmp;i++<10;head=tmp)
    {
        *tmp=create(i+100);
        tmp->next=head;
    }
    printlist(head);
}
```

and in the for loop, I am using node_t* pointer which is assign to already initialized (via `malloc`) struct outside in `create` function. But the program emits:

```
warning: ‘tmp’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   *tmp=create(i+100);

Command terminated
```

So how to assign a dereferenced pointer to already initialized data in c?

Comment: Suggestion: rewrite `create()` (and associated code) such that it returns the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you first enter the loop, `tmp` doesn't point to anything.  Because of that, it's invalid to dereference the pointer.

Also, you have a memory leak in `create`.  You dynamically allocate memory for a node but then return a copy of that node, leaving nothing to point to the allocated memory.

You can fix these issues by returning a pointer from the function:

```
node_t *create(int value){
    node_t *ret = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    ret->value=value;
    ret->next=0;
    return ret;
}
```

And subsequently saving that pointer in `tmp` in the calling function:

```
    tmp=create(i+100);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `leaving nothing to point to the allocated memory`. Once the pointer was assign to point to a address provided by malloc, return from function should not change it or? If I dereference it in the return statement, I return a value of the struct (which should be pointer to its first element under the hood), but the address should preserve?

Comment: @milanHrabos `create` was returning a *copy* of the allocated memory, not a pointer to it, so the pointer value was lost.

Comment: what does a *copy* of struct mean? A value of first element? or the second? How can you *copy* a full struct without a pointer?

Comment: @milanHrabos By assigning an instance of a struct to another as you did.  For example, `node_t x, y;  x.val=1; x.next=NULL; y=x;`

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function create should return pointer to the created dynamically node. Otherwise you will be unable to free allocated nodes because the function returns a copy of a created node.

So rewrite the function at least like

```
node_t * create(int value){
    node_t *ret = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    ret->value=value;
    ret->next=0;
    return ret;
}
```

In the for loop in main you are using an uninitialized pointer tmp. So with the function implementation of create as you defined it the loop invokes undefined behavior due to the underlined assignment

```
for(node_t*tmp;i++<10;head=tmp)
{
    *tmp=create(i+100);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    tmp->next=head;
}
```

So after changing the function create change the loop like

```
for(node_t*tmp;i++<10;head=tmp)
{
    tmp=create(i+100);
    tmp->next=head;
}
```

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int value;
    void *next;
} node_t;

void printlist(node_t*head){
    for(node_t*i=head;i;i=i->next)
        printf("%i\n",i->value);
}

node_t * create(int value){
    node_t *ret = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    ret->value=value;
    ret->next=0;
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    int i=0;
    node_t*head=0;
    for(node_t*tmp;i++<10;head=tmp)
    {
        tmp=create(i+100);
        tmp->next=head;
    }
    printlist(head);
}
```

Its output is

```
110
109
108
107
106
105
104
103
102
101
```